# How to exclude specific pages from Wordpress search results

Tags: wordpress

I have some pages that I don't want it to be included when anybody searches within my website. I tried to add the code below to my function.php but it doesn't work

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_pages_search_when_logged_in' );
function exclude_pages_search_when_logged_in($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search && is_user_logged_in() )
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 6410, 1684, 6385, 278, 6390, 865 ) ); 

    return $query;
}
```

How do I exclude some pages from the search results?

Comment: just to be sure, do you want to hide the page to logged in users only? The question was that you don't want to include that if "anybody" makes a search. This could be a problem if you are not logged in and test the function.

Comment: i want to exclude thispages from anybody that may make search not logged in users only

Comment: Remove `&& is_user_logged_in()` from the `if` construct if you want these pages to be excluded for everyone.

Comment: Did you try it without the `is_user_logged_in` clause in the `if`? That might be all that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`add_action` is what you use to create a trigger “hook” – when something happens, do-something-else.
`add_filter` is used to “hook” data change/replace. use the code below instead

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_exclude_filter' );
function my_search_exclude_filter( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_admin &amp;&amp; $query->is_search &amp;&amp; $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 9564, 1213  ) );
  }
}
```

I also described the other solutions is my blog post https://naderzad.info/web-development/wordpress-search-result/